# REST ws + Android app + web site

Tags: android, веб-программирование, rest, веб-служба

**Есть задача:** Создать Android приложение, которое будет получать данные с сервера. Также должна быть веб админка, где клиенты могут добавлять данные (картинки, цены и тд).

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что для решения задачи необходимо создать веб сервис (наприрмер REST)?
2. Если веб севис необходим (а я так и думаю, иначе как Андроид приложение будет с сервером взаимодействовать), то как здесь увязать веб админку? Это должен быть отдельный проект (веб сайт), который будет отдельным приложением и будет деплоиться на этот же сервер, где и веб сервис? Или это могут быть разные веб сервера? Или вебсервис + веб сайт должны быть одним проектом?
3. База данных у веб сервиса и веб сайта должна быть одна и та же?
4. К примеру у веб сервиса есть метод getUsers() который вызывается по адресу /users, а в админке нам нужно отобразить всех пользователей. В этом случае нам нужно из контроллера веб сайта делать запрос к методу веб сервиса getUsers() затем обработать данные и вывести их с нужным представлением, или лучше обойтись без контроллера, сделав запрос в AJAXе ? Как это обычно делается?

Answer (score 1):

1. RESTful сервис вполне подойдет для системы "запрос-ответ".
2. Я бы делал админку как привелегированного клиента. На андроиде клиент с обычными правами, а веб-приложение - клиент с админ-правами. Рассматривайте админку, как обычного клиента. Как если бы Вы делали второе приложение под андроид, где можно было бы добавлять, редактировать данные. Конечно, это получится как отдельный сайт (веб-приложение). Размещать его на той же машине или на другой - дело Ваше (если нет никаких особых примечаний, то я бы разместил на одной машине).
3. Веб сайт будет делать запрос в сервису, а сервис уже взаимодействовать с базой. Не создавайте связь между админкой и базой напрямую (ладно бы, если бы у Вас был просто один единый веб-сервис с админкой, но раз тут REST, то лучше всю работу с базой оставить ему, а админка и андроид клиент будут стучаться в сервис).
4. Не совсем понимаю вопрос (с Ajax не работал вообще). Я бы сделал в простом варианте всю адресацию для админки `/admin/что-то`, а для клиента просто `/что-то`. Но тут дело не в адресации скорее, а в том, что нужно предусмотреть механизм авторизации и аутентификации. Чтобы сервер, получая запрос, удостоверился, что этот запрос имеет право посылать клиент (будь то андроид или админка).

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ.
Получается из админка будет сначала отправлять запрос к ее бэкенду, а из бэкенда админки будем делать запрос к веб сервису? 

Нормальной ли является практикой когда админка (веб сайт) и веб сервис является одним приложением, просто некоторые методы вебсервиса отдают правильные объекты по правильным запросам? Тогда запрос будет иметь путь: дминка -> бэкенд.

Comment: Если под бэкендом админки Вы подразумеваете просто логику хранения текущих данных и логику запросов к REST сервису, то да. По поводу второго запроса: встречал разные варианты. Придерживаюсь такой логике: лучше изолировать логику системы от клиента, особенно когда клиенты могут быть кросплатформенными. Было бы вполне нормальным решением объединить админку и сервис в одно приложение, если бы это был просто сайт для пользователей, и некоторые из них были бы админами. Но так как есть мобильный клиент, лучше сделать универсальный API, а к нему  подтягивать клиентов(хоть Android, хоть iOS, хоть веб)